# A form of Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can we solve equations of the form $c \equiv a \mod b$ for finding the c?

Also, sometimes $c$ can be two different numbers, one negative and one positive, when is that possible and how does it work?

Comment: In modular arithmetic there is no distinction such as positive and negative numbers; every number is congruent to  a positive  as well as negative numbers. Take an arithmetic progression: keep subtracting the common difference from the first term and extend it infinitely on the left direction also. Then all the terms of this sequence are congruent to each other modulo the common difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the Chinese remainder theorem.

This is just one of the basic definitions in modular arithmetic.

$c \equiv a \mod b$ if and only if $b \mid c-a$.

The Chinese remainder theorem help you solve two congruences in relatively prime moduli simultaneously. This isn't the case here. Moreover, $c \equiv a \mod b$ isn't an equation in modular arithmetic, because you're not looking for any number that when it's plugged in it satisfies the equation.

Comment: If this c is unknown, how can I workout and find it?

Comment: @user3543192: I assume that you're asking how you can work out and find an integer $c$ that works. Let's work through the definitions: $c \equiv a \mod b$ if and only if $b \mid c-a$ if and only if there exists $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $bk = c-a$. Therefore $c=kb+a$ for some integer $k$. Hence, there are infinitely many integer numbers $c$ that are congruent to $a$ mod $b$ but in modular arithmetic they are all counted as one! Have you read about equivalence relations and equivalence classes?